# How to pass jwt-token to Angular2 app after succesfull auth on third-side?

Tags: c#, angular, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core

The scenario: I have 2 web-apps. One of them is [an authorization server][1] (implementing by IdentityServer4), the other is [a client][1]. They do interact by [Authorization Code grant][2].

The end-user work with the client app using Angular2 on front-end. To let her to login (through the auth server app as third side like Facebook etc) and get JWT-token (the issuer is the client app) I created the following middleware handling requests which is sended by end-user after succesfull authorization on authorization server side (i.e. the incoming request must contain auth code):

```
using IdentityModel.Client;
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
if (!httpContext.Request.Path.Equals("/api/connect/authcallback", StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
   await next(httpContext);
   return;
}

//try to get auth code from the request
string code = httpContext.Request.Form["code"];

//try to request access token from the auth server app
var tokenClient = new TokenClient("https://AuthServer.com/connect/token", ClientId, ClientSecret);
var responseToken =  await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, "http://ourcallback.com");
var token = responseToken.AccessToken;

//that's good, so create JWT-token for the end-user
var JwtToken = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CreateJwtToken());
//what should I do further?
}
```

My question is how can I pass the JWT-token to the end-user's Angular2 app? It's wrong to just send it from that point of code because Angular2 have to set it to LocalStorage. Maybe should I redirect user with the token? So can I do it (how to pass it)?
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-6
[2]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1

Comment: did you solve that issue by now?